# Web3js method.call() is returning several blocks later

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am attempting to get the updated value of a smart contract variable. The way I'm doing this is by having a while loop that is constantly checking the value of this variable.

```
while(true) {
   const value = await contract.readVariable().call();
}
```

This works just fine, but I don't get the results of this until the next mined block, which takes about 15 seconds. I wondered how I could get the results the second they are updated without waiting for the next block. Here are the exact results from my testing.

I detected that the value had changed at `12/28/2021, 3:02:42 block number 13895772`, but the new value was mined in block `13895771 at 08:02:26 PM +UTC`. As you can see, there is a 16-second delay between when I got it and when it was actually mined.

Comment: 16s seem like a normal time between mining and confirmation and sharing it across the network, but i am not involved in web3 that much

Comment: @PLASMAchicken If a block is mined, does that not count as being shared across the network?

Comment: miners fetch (some) the pending transactions, validate them, put them toghter into a block, run the algorithm on the block, if the result is ok, it is "mined", then they send it to other nodes / miners to validate, and then its officaly done

Comment: @PLASMAchicken does that mean that the time it takes for me to get the updated value is expected, what I'm seeing is a whole block later I get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

> If a block is mined, does that not count as being shared across the network?

[Please read and understand how Ethereum state update works and then about state propagation in Ethereum works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65842575/315168).

There is no guarantees for any sort of timeframe when your changed value is included in Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: Is there a way to capture the value even if it’s not propagated throughout the entire network, even if it means it could rollback later?

Comment: Currently, there is no way to simulate transactions in real-time. You can do one offs with Ganache, but it means you need to fork the whole blockchain and the delay for the simulation is several minutes.